# Android Studio - FileNotFound exception in editor

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm getting this error in the android studio ide even before hitting "run".

> Unhandled exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException

With this class:

(The function in the class is not yet being called!)

```
import java.io.*;


public class FileIO
{
public static byte[] readBinaryFileFromAssets(File file)
{
    byte[] data = null;

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    dis.readFully(data);
    dis.close();

    return data;
}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its bothering you because you haven't handled a potential file not found exception.
Surround it with try/catch or throw the exception.

```
 public static byte[] readBinaryFileFromAssets(File file)
    {
        byte[] data = null;

        DataInputStream dis = null;
        try {
            dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            dis.readFully(data);
            dis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return data;
    }
```

Note: you can automatically surround blocks in try/catch in android studio by doing alt+enter to bring up the options and then selecting "surround with try/catch"

Comment: Coming from C# development in Visual studio i didn't know about this. Also after adding the IOException the error wen't away not with the first only.

Comment: Yea, the IO exception is more like a catch all possible IO errors, while the file not found exception is a specific one. The reason you should put both, specific first, general last, is because you'll get more details about what happened. 
If you actually have a filenotfoundexception but only put IOException in the catch, the error report will just tell you an IO exception occurred which inst very helpful. If you put filenotfoundexception first it will tell you a file wasn't found and you'll know exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [checked exception](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129). If you look at the Docs for the [`FileInputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream(java.io.File)), you'll see it throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

Surround your code in a `try/catch` block to account for such an event and the error should go away. Something like:

```
try {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    //etc...
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    //Account for situations where the file can't be found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got an exception which is not being caught. You need to add a try/catch block or let the method trow an exception.

```
    public static byte[] readBinaryFileFromAssets(File file){
    try{    
    byte[] data = null;

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        dis.readFully(data);
        dis.close();

        return data;
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    //TODO something appropriate when the file isn't found
    }
return null;
    }
```

Comment: answer of Bone is same but has better layout.